# Card distribution animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, playing-cards

I am building my first game(Rummy game).I am not able to find a good animation effect for playing cards distribution .Here are the steps i am thinking the animation should have:

- The top card should rotate 70 degrees.
- I should able to see below cards when rotated.
- Then the cards from center should be distributed .it comes something like a snake-move type and it should be placed at the bottom of the table.All cards side-by-side
- All this animation should happen with in very less time.
  Please help out guys.If i have a clue how to do then i can figure out something.Thanks in advance.

Code i have written is:

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.graphics.Point;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
 import android.view.Display;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
 import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    Animation.AnimationListener{

ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4,iv5,iv6,iv7,iv8;
Animation animFadein,animMove;
int height,width;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
     width = size.x;
     height = size.y;
    iv2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    iv4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv4);
    iv5=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv5);
    iv6=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv6);
    iv7=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv7);
    iv8=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv8);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(-85,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt.setDuration(300);
    animationt.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(-65,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt2.setDuration(300);
    animationt2.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt2.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt3 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(-45,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt3.setDuration(400);
    animationt3.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt3.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt4 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(-25,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt4.setDuration(500);
    animationt4.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt4.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt5 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(5,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt5.setDuration(600);
    animationt5.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt5.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt6 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(25,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt6.setDuration(700);
    animationt6.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt6.setAnimationListener(this);
    final TranslateAnimation animationt7 = new TranslateAnimation(0, convertDpToPixel(45,this), 0, convertDpToPixel(80,this));
    animationt7.setDuration(800);
    animationt7.setFillAfter(true);
    animationt7.setAnimationListener(this);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            iv1.startAnimation(animFadein);


           iv8.startAnimation(animationt);
            iv7.startAnimation(animationt2);
           iv6.startAnimation(animationt3);
            iv5.startAnimation(animationt4);
           iv4.startAnimation(animationt5);
           iv3.startAnimation(animationt6);
           iv2.startAnimation(animationt7);

        }
    });
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.sequential);
    animMove=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.move);

    // set animation listener
    animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

    // button click event


}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // Take any action after completing the animation

    // check for fade in animation
    if (animation == animFadein) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animation Stopped",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        iv1.clearAnimation();
        iv1.setRotation(0f);
       // iv2.startAnimation(animMove);


    //    iv2.startAnimation(animationt);
    }
   /* if(animation==animMove)
    {
        iv2.clearAnimation();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv2.getWidth(), iv2.getHeight());
        lp.setMargins(con, 300, 0, 0);
        iv2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
*/
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
 }
```

sequential.xml  in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
<!-- Use startOffset to give delay between animations -->
<rotate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="70" />
<!-- Move -->

</set>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.rushiayappa.animationsample.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv8"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv7"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv6"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv5"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv4"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv3"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />
```

I did this almost as how i wanted..But the shape while dispatching cards should be like a snake move..(zigzag)

Comment: We need a lot more information to help you with this. Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (preferable and with a video/gif of what you want it to look like) and we also need to see the code you have tried so far and explanations about why that code is not working.

Comment: @XaverKapeller there you go..